importlib.reload on every import, program-wide
I work in an environment (ArcGIS Pro) that does not automatically recompile imported modules when they're edited. This requires to put an importlib.reload after each import:
import module1
from importlib import reload
reload(module1)

Obviously, this is very tedious.
Is it possible to trigger a reload upon every import, program-wide (= also in imports imported by imports, etc.)?
